# selecting elements from list of list based on length and intersection

Tags: python, list

```
l1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'],
      ['a', 'd', 'c'],
      ['a', 'e'],
      ['a', 'd', 'c'],
      ['a', 'f', 'c'],
      ['a', 'e'],
      ['p', 'q', 'r']]

l2 = [1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

I have two lists as represented above. `l1` is a list of lists and `l2` is another list with some kind of score.

Problem: For all the lists in `l1` with a score of `0` (from `l2`), find those lists which are either entirely different or have the least length.

For example: if i have the lists `[1, 2, 3]`, `[2, 3]`, `[5, 7]` all with score 0, i will choose `[5, 7]` because these elements are not present in any other lists and `[2, 3]` since it has an intersection with `[1, 2, 3]` but is of a smaller length.

How I do this now:

```
l = [x for x, y in zip(l1, l2) if y == 0]
lx = [(x, y) for x, y in zip(l1, l2) if y > 0]
c = list(itertools.combinations(l, 2))

un_usable = []
usable = []
for i, j in c:
    intersection = len(set(i).intersection(set(j)))
    if intersection > 0:
        if len(i) < len(j):
            usable.append(i)
            un_usable.append(j)
        else:
            usable.append(j)
            un_usable.append(i)

for i, j in c:
    intersection = len(set(i).intersection(set(j)))
    if intersection == 0:
        if i not in un_usable and i not in usable:
            usable.append(i)
        if j not in un_usable and j not in usable:
            usable.append(j)            

final = lx + [(x, 0) for x in usable]
```

and final gives me:

```
[(['a', 'b', 'c'], 1),
 (['a', 'd', 'c'], 1),
 (['a', 'e'], 1),
 (['a', 'd', 'c'], 2),
 (['a', 'e'], 0),
 (['p', 'q', 'r'], 0)]
```

which is the required result.

EDIT: to handle equal lengths:

```
l1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'],
      ['a', 'd', 'c'],
      ['a', 'e'],
      ['a', 'd', 'c'],
      ['a', 'f', 'c'],
      ['a', 'e'],
      ['p', 'q', 'r'],
      ['a', 'k']]

l2 = [1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]     

l = [x for x, y in zip(l1, l2) if y == 0]
lx = [(x, y) for x, y in zip(l1, l2) if y > 0]
c = list(itertools.combinations(l, 2))
un_usable = []
usable = []
for i, j in c:
    intersection = len(set(i).intersection(set(j)))
    if intersection > 0:
        if len(i) < len(j):
            usable.append(i)
            un_usable.append(j)
        elif len(i) == len(j):
            usable.append(i)
            usable.append(j)
        else:
            usable.append(j)
            un_usable.append(i)

usable = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in usable)]
un_usable = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in un_usable)]

for i, j in c:
    intersection = len(set(i).intersection(set(j)))
    if intersection == 0:
        if i not in un_usable and i not in usable:
            usable.append(i)
        if j not in un_usable and j not in usable:
            usable.append(j)            

final = lx + [(x, 0) for x in usable]
```

Is there a better, faster & pythonic way of achieving the same?

Comment: Code improvements belong in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I know but I'm also looking for a better algorithm to do the same. I posted the code as to: "What have you done?" :)

Comment: What if two lists share some numbers like `[1, 2]` and `[1, 3]`? They'd both be included in the output? And why isn't `['a', 'f', 'c']` included in the output?

Comment: `a,f,c` shares `a` with `a,e` and since the latter has a smaller length, it is selected. The case that you mentioned should have both `[1, 2]` and `[2, 3]`

Comment: however, my algorithm above will fail in this case of `[1, 2]` and `[2, 3]`.

Comment: I have updated OP to handle the case above!

Comment: So what are you saying that you should get for the example above? As far as I understood it should be `[['p', 'q', 'r'], ['a', 'e']]`, because only the last 3 lists have a 0 score, and the 1st one doesn't have any intersection with the others, and the 2nd has some, but it's the shortest.

Comment: Roughly how many distinct elements are there in all your lists? e.g., in this case, there are 9 distinct letters.

Comment: could be 1000s . There is no limit as such.

Comment: What if there's a short list like `['a']` that shares an element with a longer list `['a', 'b']`, and that one shares an element with another list like `['b', 'c', 'd']`? Since `['a', 'b']` shares an element with `['a']`, it'll be removed. So what happens to `['b', 'c', 'd']`? Is that also removed?

Comment: Can lists have repeated elements?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understood everything correctly, here is an O(N) two-pass algorithm.

Steps:

1. Select lists with zero score.
2. For each element of each zero-score list, find the length of the shortest zero-score list in which the element occurs. Let's call this the length score of the element.
3. For each list, find the minimum of length scores of all elements of the list. If the result is less than the length of the list, the list is discarded.

---

```
def select_lsts(lsts, scores):
    # pick out zero score lists
    z_lsts = [lst for lst, score in zip(lsts, scores) if score == 0]

    # keep track of the shortest length of any list in which an element occurs
    len_shortest = dict()
    for lst in z_lsts:
        ln = len(lst)
        for c in lst:
            len_shortest[c] = min(ln, len_shortest.get(c, float('inf')))

    # check if the list is of minimum length for each of its chars
    for lst in z_lsts:
        len_lst = len(lst)
        if any(len_shortest[c] < len_lst for c in lst):
            continue

        yield lst
```